# mod_proxy in apache being slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, proxy, reverse-proxy

I wanted to setup a proxy on my local computer from my apache server to my rails server at another port so I added this to my httpd.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost manage.dev:80> 
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName manage.dev
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:5000/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:5000/
</VirtualHost>
```

This allows me to access manage.dev, my ruby on rails application, from my web browser without specifying a port in the URL and without having to run rails on port 80.

It works well, however it takes up to 20 seconds to resolve each request.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to speed up the requests was to add this to my httpd.conf:

```
StartServers 14
MaxClients 128
MinSpareServers 7
MaxSpareServers 14
MaxRequestsPerChild 10000
```

Now the initial request still takes up to 20 seconds, however subsequent requests are much faster.